# Access the contents of a row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So, I am creating a login screen with UITableView. There are two textfields for email and password. When the user presses 'Login' button, I want to store the contents of those two textfields in two NSStrings. How do I do that? Here is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] init];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 30)];
            playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                playerTextField.placeholder = @"Email";
                playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

                tf = jidField = [self makeTextField:@"" placeholder:playerTextField.placeholder];
                [cell addSubview:jidField];

            }
            else {
                playerTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
                playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                playerTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;

            }
            //playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
            playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
            playerTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
           // playerTextField.tag = 0;
            //playerTextField.delegate = self;

            playerTextField.clearButtonMode = YES; // no clear 'x' button to the right
            [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

            [cell addSubview:playerTextField];

        }

    }

    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Why not to connect those two textfields with outlets and have a direct access, and I guess you have only these two cells in the table, if yes I suggest to use a static UITable also.

Comment: If one of your reasons for using a UItableView is scrolling I suggest you use a UIScrollView and assign your text fields to properties on your view controller. UITextFields have properties that allow you to modify their appearance as well.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, set tag for userid and password field and retrieve the textfields with its tag identifier. Please find following implementation of loginAction method.

```
- (void)loginAction:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *userIdRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *passwordFieldRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *userIdTableCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableview   cellForRowAtIndexPath:userIdRow];
    UITableViewCell *passwordFieldTableCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:userIdRow];

    UITextField *userIDField = (UITextField *)[userIdTableCell viewWithTag:1001];
    UITextField *passwordField = (UITextField *)[passwordFieldTableCell viewWithTag:1002];

    // You can store now text to either your instance variables or properties in the following statements
    NSLog(@"%@", userIDField.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", passwordField.text];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you have to tag your's textfields

```
if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
    playerTextField.tag = 1001;
} else {
    playerTextField.tag = 1002;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Tarek said, this is how you do it.

In your *.h file

```
@interface v1ViewController : UITableViewController
{

    UITextField IBOutlet *playerEmailTxt;
    UITextField IBOutlet *playerPassword;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField IBOutlet *playerEmailTxt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField IBOutlet *playerPassword;
```

In your *.m file

```
    ...
    @synthesize playerEmailTxt;
    @synthesize playerPassword;

    ...
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
    {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {

          if (indexPath.row == 0)
          {
                playerEmailTxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 30)];
                playerEmailTxt.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                playerEmailTxt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    playerEmailTxt.placeholder = @"Email";
                    playerEmailTxt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                    playerEmailTxt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;


                    [cell addSubview:playerEmailTxt];

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {

                playerPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 30)];
                playerPassword.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                playerPassword.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

                    playerPassword.placeholder = @"Password";
                    playerPassword.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                    playerPassword.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                    playerPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
                   [cell addSubview:playerPassword];

            }

        }

        return cell;    
    }
```

Now add your login action

```
-(IBAction)LoginAction
{
    NSMutableString *usrEmailStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", playerEmailTxt];
    NSMutableString *usrPasswdStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  playerPassword];

//Do whatever you want with these strings

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework. Seems like a perfect fit for what you're trying to do, since the framework will automatically fetch the data from your fields and store them in any data structure you wish.